# Word to express disagreement without an alternative

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word or short phrase that describes when someone disagrees with another's solution to a problem, without offering a solution. Ideally this would also convey that the person who disagrees is unwilling to compromise.

For example:

There was a ____ uproar from the local residents. They would not allow the landfill in their side of the county.

It is easy to ____-ly disagree with others ideas. If you want to contribute, offer some solutions yourself.

Senator Jones needs to lead more than ____ opposition if he wants the bill defeated. The citizens want some kind of reform now.

Comment: *Disagreement* on its own doesn't imply an alternative. Just drop the blanks and adjust the terms accordingly: "*There was an uproar*", "*It is easy to disagree*", "*needs to lead more than oppose*".

Comment: @Lawrence You are correct, but I feel that there is a word that emphasizes the lack of constructive suggestions.

Comment: Have you considered “unconstructive”?

Comment: I have. I might end up using it, but I feel that there might be a more specific word.

Comment: Any presumptive notion that a disagreement necessarily entails an alternate is just **wrong**. One can disagree with something on **merits** alone and not by **comparison** at all. Ergo, it's a question of logic, not language.

Comment: The question is based on a misconception. It's not about language.

Comment: @Kris I'm aware that disagreement does not require an alternative. I'm looking for a word that specifically draws attention to the lack of alternative suggestion, and thus, how unconstructive it may be, particularly when a solution is needed.

Comment: Have you considered your own word **unconstructive** as the solution to your problem?

Comment: At this point, it is what I'm thinking.

Answer (score 1):

I finally came up with a single word that could be dropped into all three example sentences. I don't know if it's what you had in mind, but it does convey a sense of unwillingness to compromise.

1. There was a **stubborn** uproar from the local residents. They would not allow the landfill in their side of the county.
2. It is easy to **stubborn**-ly disagree with others ideas. If you want to contribute, offer some solutions yourself.
3. Senator Jones needs to lead more than **stubborn** opposition if he wants the bill defeated. The citizens want some kind of reform now.

The use of **stubborn** in the first sentence is slightly unusual, but its meaning should still be understood.

From Merriam-Webster:

> **1 a** (1) : unreasonably or perversely unyielding : MULISH
>   (2) : justifiably unyielding : RESOLUTE
>   **b** : suggestive or typical of a strong stubborn nature • a **stubborn** jaw
>   **2** : performed or carried on in an unyielding, obstinate, or persistent manner • *stubborn* effort

Answer (score 0):

There are the words impasse and stalemate, but they are nouns, not adjectives or adverbs.

> The uproar from the local residents led to an impasse. They would not...
>
> Senator Jones needs to do more than just create a stalemate if he wants the bill defeated. The citizens ...

[impasse](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impasse) (MW)

> a predicament affording no obvious escape
>
> deadlock

[stalemate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stalemate) (MW)

> a drawn contest : deadlock;

Answer (score 0):

**[Unrelenting](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unrelenting)**

There was an **unrelenting** uproar from the local residents. They would not allow the landfill in their side of the county.

It is easy to **unrelenting**ly disagree with others ideas. If you want to contribute, offer some solutions yourself.

Senator Jones needs to lead more than **unrelenting** opposition if he wants the bill defeated. The citizens want some kind of reform now.

> 1 : not softening or yielding in determination : hard, stern an unrelenting leader
>   2 : not letting up or weakening in vigor or pace : constant the unrelenting struggle
>   — unrelentingly play  \ˌən-ri-ˈlen-tiŋ-lē\ adverb

[Merriam-Webster]